# someone explain me how to count the number of element in array using pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

this is code will print the first non repeated character in string.i had doubt in first while loop.explain me what while loop is doing.

```c
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char str[]="zoho";
    int count[256]={0},i=0;
    char *p=str;
    while(*p)
    {
        ++count[*p++];
        printf("%d",count[i++]);
    }
    p=str;
    while(*p){
        if(1==count[*p]){
            printf("The first character is :%c",*p);
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow questions must show the code in the question and not as an external link. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67767680/edit) the question by pasting in the code as formatted text.

Comment: `printf("%d",count[i++]);` the `i` looks out of place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion appears to be coming from the line `printf("%d",count[i++]);` (which it appears you added for debug purposes -- but it doesn't appear to do what you would have wanted it to do)...

There are several problems with the line. First, and what is likely causing your confusion, is there is no correlation between the value of `i` and the last filled element of `count`. `i` simply starts at `0` and is incremented by `1` each loop iteration. So it will output the elements `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` That bears no relationship to the elements of `count` you fill with `++count[*p++]` (where you increment the value at the element which corresponds to the ASCII value of the current character)

The second, and potentially critical problem with your use of `i` occurs in the case where `str` had more than `255` characters. At character `256` (`i == 256`) you begin reading beyond the end of the `count` array invoking *Undefined Behavior*. Now that will not occur with `"zoho"`, but you need to always protect your array bounds.

For what you are trying to accomplish in your code, just get rid of the variable `i` altogether and remove the line  `printf("%d",count[i++]);`. The remainder of your code will actually output the first character that appears only one time in `"zoho"` (e.g. `'z'`)

For example, you code with a slightly longer string works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[]="zohozoho!uhoh",
        *p = str;
    int count[256] = {0};
    
    while (*p) {
        ++count[(unsigned char)*p++];
    }
    
    p = str;
    while (*p) {
        if (count[(unsigned char)*p] == 1){
            printf ("The first character is : %c\n", *p);
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

(**note:** the cast of `*p` to `unsigned char` prevents `"warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]"` due to `char` being a *signed* integer value (on most systems, can be *unsigned* as well -- implementation defined). If a value in the Extended ASCII code set `128-255` is encountered, using a signed `char` as an index would result in a negative index and *Undefined Behavior*)  See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) (and Extended ASCII codes).

In C all character values are unsigned and all character functions such as `fgetc()` returning `int` read values as an `unsigned char` cast to `int`, [man 3 fgetc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) under *Return Value* and [C11 Standard - 7.21.7.1 The fgetc function(p2)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p2).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/first_nonrepeat_char
The first character is : !
```

You can rewrite your code a bit more succinctly as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* use 1st argument to program as str (default "zoho" if none) */
    char *str = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "zoho",
        *p = str;
    int count[256] = {0};
    
    while (*p) {
        ++count[(unsigned char)*p++];
    }
    
    for (p = str; *p && count[(unsigned char)*p] != 1; p++) {}
    
    if (*p)
        printf ("The first character is : %c\n", *p);
}
```

(same output)

But that is just a matter of taste and either way is fine.

**Avoid Hardcoding Your String**

Try and avoid hardcoding your test string. It is fine to provide as a default of no other argument or input is provided, but you shouldn't have to re-compile your code just to test against another string. Either pass the string to test as the first argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for), or prompt the user and take the string as input.

A very simple way to take the first argument as the string, or use `"zoho"` by default if no argument is provided is to use a simple *ternary* checking if an argument has been provided. For example you can replace your declarations of `str` and `p` to:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* use 1st argument to program as str (default "zoho" if none) */
    char *str = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "zoho",
        *p = str;
```

The to check any string, just provide it as the argument, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/first_nonrepeat_char "My dog has fleas. My cat has none. Lucky cat!"
The first character is : d
```

If I have missed the point of your questions, drop a comment below and I'm happy to help further. If not, let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: It would be better to fix the problem "array subscript has type char" instead of hiding the warning with a cast.  If the char has negative value then the access is out of bounds.  (i.e. cast to unsigned char or uint8_t instead)

Comment: Rather than a temporary value, e.g. `int index = (unsigned char)*p;` a cast to `unsigned char` eliminates the potential for a sign-extended index for Extended ASCII codes and the temporary index -- though it is arguable which would be the most readable.